# Spring boot admin server not showing u\eureka clients registered on eureka server

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

Below is my eureka server application main class

```
    package com.example.restaurant.server.startup;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.EnableAdminServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAdminServer
public class RestaurantEurekaServerApplication {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(RestaurantEurekaServerApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Here is the application.properties file for same

```
    spring.application.name=RestaurantEurekaServer
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:9091/
server.port=9091
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
security.basic.enabled= false   
management.security.enabled= false
eureka.instance.health-check-url=/actuator/health
eureka.instance.home-page-url=/actuator/info
spring.boot.admin.context-path=/admin
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* 
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

The problem is my eureka server dashboard shows the clients registered on it but when i navigate to spring boot admin,it shows 0 applications registered

Pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestaurantEurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
              <start-class>com.example.restaurant.server.startup.RestaurantEurekaServerApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

              <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
      </dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.codecentric/spring-boot-admin-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

in application.properties, the `eureka.client.fetch-registry` should be `true`. With this, SBA can fetch the registration from eureka server.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after working on it for couple of days i figured it out

I had not set **spring.boot.admin.client.url** property in client due to which client was not aware on which server admin is running.
So 2 properties that i added in client are

```
    spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:9095
spring.boot.admin.client.name=""//client will be registered in spring boot admin with his name
```

Also added maven dependency for spring boot admin in each client.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:9091/
```

needs to be:

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set in **server**

```html
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

and

```html
@EnableDiscoveryClient
```

and you dependencies below is wrong:

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

only need dependency:

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version> # change to your case
</dependency>
```